# Run SQL script on Attunity in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2017, attunity

Currently I am running a script in sqldeveloper to get my data from oracle and dump into CSV file and then I import CSV file into SQL Server. Now, I have VS 2017 and I am trying to get same data into SQL server from Oracle database through Attunity driver.

I could connect oracle database using Oracle Source in data flow but at this point I am stuck, I don't know how to run my existing script which has multiple multiple SQL commands - in first line I alter my session to point to correct schema followed by setting some variables, environment setting and select statements.

Comment: Can you provide the whole command?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provided the SQL command, i will give you some insights:

In the Oracle Attunity Source if you select the `SQL Command` access mode, **you can write any complex SQL Command** even if it contains multiple commands but you must be aware that **the first select statement that return a result set (not used to set a variable value) will be considered as source**.

## Possible workaround

If there you are generating data from multiple select statement try using `UNION ALL`, so all select statement are considered as one command. Or, try inserting all data into a temp table then select data from these table at the end of the whole SQL command.

Comment: In this particular case I can't do union, I have to run script. Can I run PL-SQL code instead?

Comment: The SQL Command must be written with the source engine syntax. I am not sure if it supports all PLSQL functiinalities. You must try it